# @NotBlank doesn't seem to work

Tags: forms, hibernate, spring, validation, registration

1) I am using Spring / Hibernate validator for validation, to check whether a field has only whitespaces or is left balnk i am using `@NotBlank` (`import org.springmodules.validation.bean.conf.loader.annotation.handler.NotBlank;`) annotation on "String Name". but after putting the `@NotBlank` annotation, the field is not getting validated.

My Controller class looks like.

```
public String addPerson(
      @ModelAttribute("userregistration")@Valid UserRegistration userRegistration ,
      BindingResult result,Model model){
}
```

2) What is the other way of doing the validation ( for checking the only white spaces), if a user enters his/her full name (with a space in between) it should be validated, and a message is thrown when a user enters only white spaces?

Answer (score 1):

- Try to remove the @ModelAttribute annotation
- Check that the validation is enabled (in normal case: `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` is enoguht)
- Check that the JSR 303 validator implemplementation is deployed